# Modelica: Selecting a direction (package) using a list in OpenModelica

Tags: function, listview, model, package

I would like to know if there is a way to use different directions of packages with functions with a list where I can select options. I have my own library where I have programmed functions to calculate thermo-physical properties of some fluids (algorithms not available in open libraries). I also know how to create a selection list to select a fluid (using a type and enumeration). The problem is that I cannot make that the direction (where the function is) may be connected with the list.

I have functions for thermo-physical properties (rho_PT, cp_T, k_PT, etc) of dry air and nitrogen. Each gas has its own package with the functions of properties. For example, the directions of function for density in the air package is "Project.Fluids.Air.rho_PT". For nitrogen is similar (Project.Fluids.Nitrogen.rho_PT). If I like to calculate density of air, there should be an equation as:

rho = Project.Fluids.Air.rho_PT(P,T);

I also have created a selection list using the following code in the variable section:

```
  type GasType = enumeration(Air, Nitrogen);
  parameter GasType Gas = GasType.Air;
```

This code generates a list when I use the model, so I can select the fluid I would like to use on simulations (with "air" as default).

The problem is that I cannot find the way to connect this selection list with the directions in the packages. For example, if I select "Nitrogen" on the list, then to make possible that the previous equation be transformed automatically as:

rho = Project.Fluids.Nitrogen.rho_PT(P,T);

So the model uses the function rho_PT defined in the Nitrogen package instead of the default package of air.

Comment: Let's say if Air and Nitrogen is 'gasMedium' you can introduce the 'gasMedium' as replaceable and then redeclare them as Air and Nitrogen in the implementation level.

Comment: Create a general parameter 'medium' of type GasType and implement the code with that parameter name and implement rho = Project.Fluids.medium.rho_PT(P,T..  . But I am not sure if this works!

Comment: I tried something similar, but it didn't work. The problem is that the direction Project.Fluids.medium does not exist (the package "medium"). I tried also to define the direction as a variable, but I didn't find a way to do it.